# How to clean up older data for a dictionary of dataframes?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

This is a snippet of my code. I need to clean up one day of older data. how do we do that for a dictionary of dataframes?

```
    master_train_dict = {}
    for id in list_of_id:
        temp_df = df.loc[df["id"] == id].copy(deep=False)
        temp_df.drop('id', axis=1, inplace=True)
        temp_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        alert_list = list(temp_df["title"])
        train_embedding = get_embeddings(alert_list, model)
        temp_df["train_embedding"] = train_embedding
        master_train_dict[parent_id] = 
        temp_df[["title","train_embedding","@timestamp"]]
        #master_train_dict[parent_id] = temp_df
    global master_dict
master_dict = master_train_dict    
print(master_dict)
#clean up function
if len(master_dict)>0:
    d = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=1, minutes= 0)
    master_dict=master_dict[id]['@timestamp']>d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(master_dict)
```

Comment: Where does *parent_id* derive? Shouldn't it be *id* in `master_train_dict[id] = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider working in defined methods and use `groupby` for building list or dict of subsetted data frames. Then call functions via dictionary comprehensions.

```
def build_df(sub):
   sub_df.drop('id', axis=1, inplace=True)
   sub_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

   alert_list = list(sub_df["title"])
   train_embedding = get_embeddings(alert_list, model)

   sub_df["train_embedding"] = train_embedding
   sub_df = sub_df.reindex(["title","train_embedding","@timestamp"], axis="columns")

   return sub_df

master_train_dict = {i:build_df(g) for i, g in df.groupby(["id"])}


def clean_df(df):        
    d = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=1, minutes= 0)
    df = df[df['@timestamp'] > d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]   

    return df 

clean_master_train_dict = {k:clean_df(v) for k, v in master_train_dict.items()}
```